# Duvida em consulta com EntityFramework

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework

como faço essa consulta com `EntityFramework`?

com `lambda` ou `linq`

```
SELECT t0051_id_medicamento, t0100_lote, SUM(t0100_qtde) FROM t0100_historico 
GROUP BY  t0051_id_medicamento, t0100_lote;
```

Comment: Fale o nome da classe da sua tabela t0100_historico se puder ajudar.

Comment: o nome da classe é Historico

Comment: Ok, tenta isso: var db = new DbContext(); var resultado = db.DbSet<Historico>().ToList().GroupBy( new { p.Id, p.Lote }).Select(s => new Historico { Id = s.First().Id, Lote = s.First().Lote, Quantidade = s.Sum(sum => sum.Quantidade) }).ToList();

Comment: @WilsonSantos Se houver muitos registros, sua expressão não será legal, pois ela primeiro traz todos os registros de historico - que provavelmenta serão MUITOS - para depois fazer os agrupamentos e sumarizações.

Answer (score 2):

Assumindo que sua tabela `t0100_historico` é representada pela entidade `Historico`, então sua expressão lambda ficará algo parecido com isso:

```
db.DbSet<Historico>()
    .GroupBy(new { p.Id, p.Lote })
    .Select(s => new { s.First().Id, Lote, Total = s.Sum(sum => sum.Quantidade)})
    .ToList();
```